# Neo4j 2.3.2 cluster fails to start because of Unknown replication strategy

Tags: neo4j

After upgrading to 2.3.2 I am getting the following error when starting up the cluster.

Starting getting this in 2.3.2 upgrade and neo4j cluster fails to start:

```
2016-01-22 00:54:42.499+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@483013b3' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown replication strategy
at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.transaction.TransactionPropagator$1.getReplicationStrategy(TransactionPropagator.java:115)
at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.transaction.TransactionPropagator.start(TransactionPropagator.java:175)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
... 14 more
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue seems to be related to the updates made to the ha.tx_push_strategy setting in conf/neo4j.properties. With this setting at ha.tx_push_strategy=fixed the error occurs. When choosing a more specific strategy i.e. ha.tx_push_strategy=fixed_ascending the error goes away and the cluster forms correctly.

The push strategy determines a tie breaker where if tx ids are the same, which server id is pushed to next. The new strategies are fixed_descending and fixed_ascending. While the default of fixed_descending is the default for this version, fixed_ascending is the better choice because the election strategy uses an ascending order when determining which instance is elected as the next master. Thus using fixed_ascending reduces the chances for branched data under certain situations.